# I'm trying to select the adjacent sibling of "this" in jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors

$(this+"p").slideDown("slow");

$(this)+$("p").slideDown("slow");

$("this+p").slideDown("slow");

does not work.

Comment: Thanks to Tim Ridgely and S Pangborn

Comment: This `$("this+p").slideDown("slow");` should work as it is W3C standardised for HTML5/CSS3 - Looks like jQuery need to implement this still (Jan 2013) - Hurrrrry up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Next](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(this).next("p").slideDown("slow")
```

Make sure that the "p" element is directly adjacent, though.  Otherwise you'll want to use nextAll.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect because you cannot select DOM elements with next. Only elements with an ID or Class. Instead ise `.children()` -1

Comment: Use `children()` to get an **adjacent** item? Wouldn't that return children of `this`?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, your syntax is bad. You should use the jQuery [Sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function:

```
$(this).siblings().find("p").slideDown("slow");
```

The jQuery API site is awesome for looking stuff like this up, I rely on it nearly daily. I'd keep an eye on it.

Comment: Syntax is not bad. It is actually a standardized W3C syntax- But jQuery does not interpret it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery have not seemed to apply this? Possibly the syntax we are trying to use is incorrect.

`next()` can only select elements with an ID or Class - Not just a naked dom element as expected.

Instead use. **>** means select first level decends only.

`$('body > div').hide();`

But this gives the exact same result

`$('body').children('div').hide();`

But,

- Next
- `$('body + div').hide();`

and

- Previous
- `$('body ~ div').hide();`

Do not seem to work as expected? But [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/hierarchy-selectors/) use it as example for CSS selection...

Possibly there is a complex syntax to achieve this but I could not figure it out...